# Quarantine mails before sending with smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm sending mails form a Python script with `smtplib`. I'm wary that there may be unforeseen bugs in my script that would cause it to erroneously send mails to all customers from the production database. Is there any way to temporarily store the mails before sending them? Another mail library maybe?

I still want to send the mails if they are ok, so just logging is not an option.

Comment: If you've got the wrong mailing list or a bug in your software, how does a "quarantine" help?  What's wrong with ordinary unit testing?

Comment: Something along the lines "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is." There are some difference between the production and test system that weren't anticipated (and therefore not tested). The bugs will be ironed out and thoroughly tested, but sending an email is something that's irreversible.

Comment: What?  How does a "quarantine" help?  Please explain the use case for this "quarantine".  What does it do?  Who uses it?  Who's the actor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1: Set up a local Postfix server and configure it to put all e-mails on hold. Then manually inspect the mail queues after running your script. Release the e-mails when you see that everything is good.

I am no postfix expert, so I'm unsure about the details. Here's a man page with some info: http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html (look for the HOLD action).

2: Use a command-line option to your script:

```
def sendmail(args, recipient):
    if args.dryrun:
        print "Would send to " + recipient
    else:
        print "Sending to " + recipient
        smtp.sendmail(...)
```

.

```
$ send_emails.py --dryrun
Would send to aa@aa.com
...
Would send to bb@bb.com

$ send_emails.py
Sending to aa@aa.com
Sending to bb@bb.com
```

Comment: I have something like option 2 in place, but in this staging environment where I operate on live data and really want to send mails, it's not enough.

Comment: In that case, I would go with suggestion 1.